# Toggle and focus element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

I would like to hide a div and show it when the use select a drop button (like google showing questions in google search results). After some googling i found a way for this. I had used the below jquery to toggle between two states(show/hide) for a div.

```js
function showDiv(a) {
  $("#" + a).toggle("slow");
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" onclick="showDiv('element')">Show</a>
<div id="element" class="hidden">
Hidden content
</div>
```

Now the problem is that it first shows the div. When i click the link it hides. But that's not what i need. I need to hide the div and it should only be shown when i click the link. Also the focus on the div is lost when i toggle between the states which is bad. Can anybody help me correct this. I need to focus the div on show as well as hide.

Comment: `$("#" + a).toggle("slow").focus()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this inside your `showDiv(a)` function:

```
$("#"+a).toggle("slow").focus()
```

If you want to remove focus:

```
$("#"+a).blur();
```

Comment: I had previously tried the same., but it's not working.

Comment: It is shown by default. Is there any way to hide the div.

Comment: With that style="display: none;" or $(yourElement).hide();

Comment: It worked friend. The style was given in css file so i gave an inliner in the html now it works. The problem that i lost focus was because  of the href="#". I removed it. Now it works perfectly.